# Unable to execute javascript loaded from external html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to execute 3 javascript commands on the page
`http://ringvaart.toervolger.nl/nl/tour_2/livepagina/?mode=default`
by loading it into my own div, but I fail to execute the commands. The commands

```
toggleAllSelected();
setActiveTeamId(64);
toggleSelectedTeamId(40);
```

are able to execute on the original page, but they are not defined in my own javascript and I therefore am not able to execute them.

Can anyone please help me out?

By the way, due to contraints executing them on the original page is not an option.

Kind regards!

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="ringvaart"></div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ringvaart").html( "<object data='http://ringvaart.toervolger.nl/nl/tour_2/livepagina/?mode=default' style='width:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; height:100%;'/>").ready(
        function(){
            toggleAllSelected();
            setActiveTeamId(64);
            toggleSelectedTeamId(40);
        }
    );

});
</script>

<style >
#ringvaart{
    width: 1920px;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Is it able to know which `js` of that particular `URL` has this function?

Comment: Yes, the JS can be found at

http://ringvaart.toervolger.nl/website/105/pages/livepage/default/resources/js/crude_selection_panel.js
http://ringvaart.toervolger.nl/website/105/pages/livepage/default/resources/js/crude_active_team_panel.js

Comment: Try adding the `script` in your head and specify its path as  the above `url` and then try calling this functions!! Just a wild guess! Might work! I am not able to replicate this in fiddle as its not allowing to get the js file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is not possible to access inline page of different domain. But if your page and embedded page are in same domain (ringvaart.toervolger.nl), then it is possible. Load the page in iframe

```html
<iframe id="inlinePage" src="http://ringvaart.toervolger.nl/nl/tour_2/livepagina/?mode=default"></iframe>
```

Then get to the contentWindow of the iframe to access the global variables

```js
document.getElementById('inlinePage').contentWindow
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it is not on the same domain and we are not able to take that route.

Comment: Use can make use of the Window.postMessage() API if the target website have implement the required functionality